# Socket: Reading UDP Packet

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I've been searching about this question, but i couldn't understand the question since it was not really general, I wouldn't find the solution to read UDP packets that contain UTF-8 text for example.

So i make a socket, that makes a UDP packet that contains UTF-8 text, and i send it like this:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 80
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, 
             socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Lets define this as `sender.py`.

Now i want to make a `reciever.py` script that will be executed after `sender.py`.

How can i make that? I've heard of         `Data, addr = udp.recvfrom(1024)` but i'm not entirely sure how it works/how to use it.

So whenever i execute them together, `Reciever.py` can print UTF-8 text of UDP packet sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want the receiver to do several things:

1. Create a socket `sock` using `socket.socket`.
2. Bind to the socket using `sock.bind`.
3. In an infinite loop, execute: `data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)`.
4. Now the received data is available for your use and you can handle it as you wish.

Note that the receiver will sleep, waiting until a message appears in the socket it has bound to. After handling the data, the loop will execute once again and the receiver will go back to sleep.

`1024` corresponds to the maximum size message you can receive (around `1024` characters, since `1` character = `1` byte. If you want to be able to receive larger messages, make this value larger.

See https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication for a detailed code example.